# 'date_subscribed' doesn't have a default error when running insert SQL

Tags: laravel

I get the error:

> 'date_subscribed' doesn't have a default value

When running this SQL:

```
insert into `companys` (`title`, `idNo`, `expiration_date`, `slug`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
```

This is my migration file:

```
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('companys', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title',150)->unique();
        $table->string('slug',150);
        $table->varchar('idNo');
        $table->date('date_subscribed');
        $table->date('expiration_date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this may help you:

Use `Carbon` class on the top of file Like this `use Carbon\Carbon;`

```
public function up() 
{ 
    Schema::create('companys', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title',150)->unique();
        $table->string('slug',150);
        $table->varchar('idNo');
        $table->date('date_subscribed')->default(Carbon::now()->toDateString());
        $table->date('expiration_date')->default(Carbon::now()->toDateString());
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **nullable()** or **default(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString())** for this

```
     public function up() 
     { 
              Schema::create('companys', function (Blueprint $table) { 
                       $table->increments('id'); 
                       $table->string('title',150)->unique(); 
                       $table->string('slug',150);
                       $table->varchar('idNo'); 
                       $table->date('date_subscribed')->nullable(); 
                       $table->date('expiration_date')->nullable(); 
                       $table->timestamps();
             }); 
     }
```